# What should I do if I have a downvoted question with upvoted answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, voting, down-votes

I posted [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/209876/does-stabilizing-reset-your-death-saving-throw-counter), and it keeps getting downvoted. However, the system won't let me delete it. What should I do about this? Should I vote to close it?

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning: Because our site rates positive feedback more highly than negative feedback, even though the question is downvoted it will likely remain a net positive source of reputation for you.  Currently it is at +4/-7 for votes, which is +40/-14, for a net of +26 reputation.

Comment: Amusingly, my answer pointing out the deletion function is operated by moderation here, was itself deleted by moderation, illustrating they have the capability to do so. That said, if moderation continues to decline for whatever reason, keep in mind that StackExchange (not local moderation) has the ultimate responsibility to take down the content in question.

Comment: @sgfit Kind of... it's not really gone. "Deleted" is just "Locked down and hidden from users without enough reputation." I can still see it.

Comment: @sgfit *Again* - you were told that before but content won't be deleted "on a whim". Your answer would have been deleted because it gave completely misleading information. You persist disseminating false and deceptive advice and fail to mention the multiple things you've been told about why that is incorrect.

Answer (score 10):

### You learn from it and move on.

There’s nothing to be done with the question. It does not need to be closed, as none of our reasons for closure apply to it, nor should it be deleted, as none of our reasons for deletion apply to it.

What you can do is *learn from it and do better next time*. The reason (I suspect) the question is getting downvoted is that its answer is spelled out quite plainly in the first place one should think to look, the section in the rules about death saving throws. I don’t actually know if you checked the rules or not before you asked your question. If you did, and you missed the line that answered your question, that’s fine, I’ve done that before too. But you should always try to do some research before asking a question here, and share with us what you’ve already done to find the answer. Our help center article on asking good questions states:

> Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

This is what seems missing from your question, and going through this exercise may have prevented you from needing to ask it at all.

Finally, in case someone else mentions this, [SE staff is able to disassociate a post from your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96746/674198), but requesting this be done simply because you are getting downvoted probably isn’t an appropriate use of this feature or staff time.

Comment: In addition to OP learning from it, the negative votes and comments explaining negative votes are a useful signpost for future users.

Comment: In case you DID check the rulebook and simply missed it: I think there would probably still be fewer downvotes if you added a "I checked section X in the PHB, but couldn't find anything" disclaimer.